# ACF text previous post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a ACF text field.

I want to use the previous post on these texts, but my code doesn't work...

This is this line that doesn't work :

```
var r = parseInt('<?php the_field('red', $prev_post->ID); ?
```

Here's my code :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".next_image_cover a").hover(

        function() {

        var r = parseInt('<?php the_field('red', $prev_post->ID); ?>'); 
        var g = parseInt('<?php the_field('green', $prev_post->ID); ?>'); 
        var b = parseInt('<?php the_field('blue', $prev_post->ID); ?>'); 


        $("body").stop().animate({"background-color": "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")"}, "200");
        },
        function() {

        $("body").stop().animate({"background-color": "#e6e6e6"}, "200");

    });
```

Comment: The line you marked as *doesn't work* is fine. Are you sure `$prev_post` is correctly instantiated with a `WP_Post` object? Have you tried to `var_dump()` it?

Comment: Are these '<?php' tags running server side? So is an integer showing up when you view the source client side? If not you should know that you can't run php client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use php variable in javascript -

```
parseInt('<?php the_field('red'); ?>', **$prev_post->ID**);
```

Comment: parseInt('<?php the_field('red',$prev_post->ID); ?>');

Comment: It simply doesn't work and it cancel my previous codes

Comment: Yes you can. You can output HTML with PHP. You can place Javascript inside HTML and, of course, you can output Javascript with PHP. There's nothing wrong in doing, for example: `<script>var url = '<?php $url = get_bloginfo('url'); echo $url; ?>';</script>`

Comment: var r = parseInt('<?php $url = the_field('red', $prev_post->ID); echo $url; ?>';

It is correct ? Because it does'nt work

Comment: No, @user3870112. This was only a sample code non related to your question. Btw, I've seen the original _before-edit_ question and now I get your comment Rohan.